# how to scrub ssn while preserving their uniqueness?

Tags: python, privacy

To reduce privacy risk, I should scrub the SSNs from the input. I need to scrub them in a way that preserves uniqueness. E.g. if I have `111-11-1119`, `111-11-1119`, and `111-11-1118`, we could number `111-11-1119` as 1 and `111-11-1118` as 2.

What's the best way to do that?

Comment: What format is your original data in?

Comment: If you are reading a single file you can store the originals and the substitutions in a dictionary. But if you want the identity of the substitutions to persist over multiple files (what you called 2 yesterday you will call 2 again today) then you will have to store the mappings in a database or something, and that just moves the problem. So what you want to do is much easier said than done.

Comment: please show us your data and also your expected result. for example; is this your data = ["111-11-1119", "111-11-1119", and "111-11-1118"]  and expected result = ["1", "2"] ??.

Comment: `re.sub` supports callable as a replacement. Write a function that uses a global dictionary of sanitized SSNs, storing replacement values

Comment: any crypographically secure one way hash. SHA-256 maybe

Comment: Depends on your use case. For "have I seen this one before" a hash would work well; but if you need to be able to see part or all of the value later, a different approach is required. If e.g. 111-11 is not sensitive information, but the last group is, you could replace the last group with a hash (whilst of course taking care to avoid making it easy to reverse engineer - maybe hash the entire input so that two SSNs with the same final group don't get the same hash).

Comment: Original data is in Json

Comment: Marat can you gimme an example?

Answer (score 1):

To remove SSN or other standardized PII while preserving uniqueness, you will need a cryptographic hash function. This is not something that you should try to implement yourself with an incrementing ID and dict. To take PII seriously, you will need to do a bit of research to understand what a crytographic hash is doing and how it can protect the data.

For a previous discussion, see [Cryptographic hash functions in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27300409/cryptographic-hash-functions-in-python)

Some of these might be helpful as introductions:

- https://komodoplatform.com/cryptographic-hash-function/
- https://www.coursera.org/lecture/cryptocurrency/cryptographic-hash-functions-gFEJL
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function

Comment: How is hash any better than simple replacement? Both make it impossible to guess the original.

Comment: There are only about a billion SSNs, so if the code and "deidentified" data are available, it would be trivial to create a rainbow table, crosswalking all billion directly back to their originals. A properly keyed cryptographic hash prevents this.

Comment: A PRF is not sufficient as it has values where H(a) == H(b) where a != b. A PRP has the property that for a limited domain of values P(a) == P(b) if and only if a == b.

Comment: Original data is in JSON, hash is too complicated, i dont need to show any part of the ssn at all. is ti possible to do it with List?

Answer (score 1):

Tokenization or Format-Preserving Encryption (FPE) are appropriate anonymization technique for primary keys in PII data like SSN.  Both can provide consistency and uniqueness.

You can use a NIST approved [FPE algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption#Implementations) where a python library is now available for [FF3](https://pypi.org/project/ff3/).  Alternatively, you could create a tokenizer using python regular expression generator library [src-yield or hypothesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17962455/random-data-generator-mathing-a-regex-in-python)
[image]